# TypeError: Cannot create property 'next' on string '/:id'

Tags: javascript, node.js

i was trying to build an api for a travel company but the error "TypeError: Cannot create property 'next' on string '/:id'" is comming up . all the function listed here are created

```
const express = require('express');
const port = 3000
const app = express();
const tourRouter = express.Router();
tourRouter.route('/').
    get(getAllTours)
    .post(createTour);
tourRouter('/:id').
    get(getTour)
    .patch(updateTour)
    .delete(deleteTour);
app.use('/api/v1/tours', tourRouter)
app.listen(port)
```

and the error is

```
 req.next = next;           ^
TypeError: Cannot create property 'next' on string '/:id'
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\Desktop\node\starter\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:160:12)
    at router
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you forgot `.route` here:

```
tourRouter('/:id').
```

It should be

```
tourRouter.route('/:id').
```